# How will MFC load the string resource?

Tags: string, mfc, localization, resources

I just read the article about localization in MFC at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fkteez0 , and have one question:

If I make an application called MyApp.exe and then make a Germany localized resource DLL as MyAppDeu.dll. There are two string resources in MyApp.exe, that is, string1 and string2. I make a German-version of string1 and put it in MyAppDeu.dll, but do not make a German-version for string2.

Then in a system with German language UI, what MFC will do for string1 and string2 when MyApp.exe is launched?

Thanks

Alan

Comment: It will crash when you try to load the non-existent string.

Answer (score 1):

If it is named in a way that the MFC core undertannds this language will be used.
CWinApp::InitInstance calls a function named LoadAppLangResourceDLL. It searches the module with DEU, ENU... according to the current System language or selected MUI.

So if you call the base class CWinApp::InitInstance, everything is done. I don't know since what MFC version this works. As far as I remember this was introduced in VS-2008 or VS-2005...

In detail: This InitInstance set the internal resource handle. Resources are loaded from a module or modules, that are defined via AfxSetResourceHandle. There is a function AfxGetResourceHandle that is used before any Load... function is executed.

You are still responsible to set the

So all resource loads are simply redirected to another module. This words for every MFC Instance (DLL and EXE).

Comment: So actually it will have problems when loading string2, since MyAppDEU.dll is loaded and the string2 does not exist in it?

Comment: Yes you will. ALL resources must be in the new DLL. I have a Special program that helps me to customize and create such RC files for the localized DLLs.